# Deploying a Content File *Link* for a VS2008 Website project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment

I have added an Xml configuration file to a web project in VS2008 using the “Add as Link” option on the “Add Existing Item” dialog. The Xml file is common to a number of other web projects within the solution so it exists in the Solution level directory. I have used the file link functionality to avoid a unique copy being added to each web project.

> ```
> SolutionFolder
>     SharedConfigSettings.config
>     WebProject1Folder
>     WebProject2Folder
> ```

### Problem

The problem is that the linked file is not deployed. I need the file to be copied to the root of the web application so that it is in the same location as the web.config file.

### I have tried

1) Setting the file properties on the link as...

> Build Action: Content
>   Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

...results in the file not being copied at all

2) Setting the file properties on the link as...

> Build Action: Content
>   Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

...results in the file being copied to the Bin directory below the web application root.

3) Post build event to copy the file. This works but is messy to implement because it requires additional steps to get this to work on the build server.

Is there a way that this can be done using the standard options available in the project file?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you get a solution?

Comment: Sadly no. These links are just not understood by MS Build. They are only meant for linking files at design-time. And I never found an alternative.

Comment: See this blog for more information and a potential workaround: 
http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamesdawson/archive/2008/06/03/using-linked-files-with-web-application-projects.aspx